# Syntax error when Insert to Access using OleDb

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I do not have a lot of experience in vb.net, but I am trying to use OleDB to insert a record with String,string,Yes/no(studentname, number, gender). However when I insert it , there's a exception raised stating that I have invalid syntax for the "insert into" query. I could not spot the error.

Test case:

```
txtName.Text = "asdasdasd"
txtPhone.Text = "123456789"
rGender.Checked = True
```

Here's the code:

```
    cmd = New OleDbCommand()
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Student] (StudentName, Number, Gender) VALUES(@Name,@Number,@Gender)"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtPhone.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", rGender.Checked)
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the Problem with field name "Number", its a keyword in MSAccess - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335.

Comment: I did not remember that there was a list of reserve keyword. I just work with access for 2 or 3 times before so thank you very much Anuraj

Answer (score 2):

Number is `reserved` word,

```
INSERT INTO [Student] ([StudentName], [Number], [Gender]) VALUES(@Name,@Number,@Gender)
```

Comment: THis works after long time to search a solution for "has a syntax problem"